# Where clause in Openquery

Tags: sql-server, openquery

I am trying to get values from an Openquery. Can you please tell me how would I translate this where clause into an Openquery statement?

```
select * 
from openquery(
    XYZ,  
    'select 
         concat(RTRIM(LTRIM(Digit1)), '','' 
               ,RTRIM(LTRIM(Digit2)), '', ''
               , RTRIM(LTRIM(Digit3))) as my_col
         , my_category
     FROM adventure.mytable
     where CAST(CONCAT(Year, Month, Day) as date) =  
           cast(dateadd(day,datediff(day, 1,GETDATE()),0) AS date)
    ')
```

The statement works fine if used outside of an Openquery.

Sample Data:

```
Digit1  Digit2  Digit3  Month       Day Year    Category
5       3       2       December    18  2017    Day 
3       0       5       December    18  2017    Evening
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Are these `CONCAT(Year, Month, Day)` columns in `mytable`?

Comment: Yes, they are separate columns that I am trying to convert to a date field. I am not getting any errors, but it is not bring any data as I expect to.

Comment: As @WEI_DBA seems to be hinting at, those are reserved keywords. Try wrapping them in brackets.

Comment: Sample data would be good to see.

Comment: @WEI_DBA,   

This is how the data looks like outside of the Openquery:

Digit1 Digit2 Digit3 Month Day Year Category
5 3 2 December 18 2017 Day
3 0 5 December 18 2017 Evening

Comment: `Category <> my_category`, is this just a typo?

Comment: @WEI_DBA, yes it is. What I am trying to do is get the previous day data concatenating the fields Year, Month and Day against yesterday's date. Thanks.

Comment: So if it works fine not using `OpenQuery`, then what data source is `XYZ`?

Comment: Yes, XYZ is my linkedserver.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a test run and it executed successfully, please see the attached image below:

[image: Test_run]

Thanks.

Comment: @sathishcse, if I add quotes it becomes a string and it gives this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". Thanks

Comment: try giving the complete reference: DB.SCHEMA.TABLE instead of SCHEMA.TABLE.

Comment: I have actually tried that as well and still did not return any data. I even tried to pass as a parameter and still wouldn't work.